# can't return back to question detail page after editing answer in django

Tags: python, django

This is the code of my update answer

```
def Update_Answer(request, id):
    ans = Answer.objects.get(pk=id)
    quest = Question.objects.get(pk=id)
    answerform = AnswerForm(request.POST or None,instance=ans)
    if answerform.is_valid():
         answerform.save()
         messages.success(request, 'Answer has been submitted.')
         return redirect('detail', id)



    return render(request, 'update_answer.html',
                  {
                   'form': answerform
                   })
```

Here when i select an answer to be edited, it generates a url with answer id. But after i edit my answer, i automatically want to return back to question id .

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo?

```
ans = Answer.objects.get(pk=id)
quest = Question.objects.get(pk=id)
```

can't be right. one of them has `pk=id` and the other must have `pk=something_else`. Your url presumably contains both question and answer id.

If that's not it we need to see your url definitions

Answer (score 0):

Update the question id istead answer id inredirect, use the right foreign key name. ***

> return redirect('detail', ans.question.id)

---

```
def Update_Answer(request, id):
    ans = Answer.objects.get(pk=id)
    quest = Question.objects.get(pk=id)
    answerform = AnswerForm(request.POST or None,instance=ans)
    if answerform.is_valid():
         answerform.save()
         messages.success(request, 'Answer has been submitted.')
         return redirect('detail', ans.question.id)



    return render(request, 'update_answer.html',
                  {
                   'form': answerform
                   })
```